# Angular uses comma instead of dot as decimal separator after changing culture

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core

I added multiple cultures for localization feature, set NumberDecimalSeparator and CurrencyDecimalSeparator to "." for all of them. However on frontend Angular still shows comma when changing culture to "es".

Startup.cs

```
private List<CultureInfo> cultures = new List<CultureInfo>()
            {   new CultureInfo("es"),
                new CultureInfo("en"),
                ....
            };
```

In ConfigureServices:

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
               opts =>
               {

                   cultures.ForEach(c => c.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".");
                   cultures.ForEach(c => c.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = ".");
                   opts.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new CustomRequestCultureProvider(context =>
                   {
                       var userLang = context?.Request?.Cookies["locale"]?.ToString();   
                       var lang = string.IsNullOrEmpty(userLang) ? "es" : userLang;   
                       return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(lang, "en"));
                   }));                       
                   opts.SupportedCultures = cultures;                   
                   opts.SupportedUICultures = cultures;
               });
```

In Configure:

```
var op = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
 app.UseRequestLocalization(op.Value);

 app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddRedirect("index.html", "/"));

 app.UseMvc(routes =>
                {routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); });
```

In controller action I am checking if there is comma was replaced with dot:

```
var rqf = Request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();           
 var culture = rqf.RequestCulture.Culture;
```

Yes,  it was:
[image]

Apparently Angular ignores those settings, any ideas? 
Any info how culture is passed to Angular? 
Any way set Response culture to "en"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be pretty much out of luck. The locale is not currently related with the front end depiction of the currency.

[Feature request in the angular repository](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25461). The current solution offered (it seems that this global currency handler will not be applied even in the 9.0 version of angular), is to apply everywhere the currency pipe.

Seems like it is considered a bad practice to correlate the currency with the locale.

> @MickL Let me give you an example on why the approach to only use the LOCALE_ID would cause problems.
>   Let's say I have a app that provides German (de) and English (en). And I have prices in Euro in this app.
>   Your approach means that when I change the LOCALE_ID to en that my prices switch from Euro to GBR.
>   When using a CURRENCY_ID those are separated and can change separate.

This pretty much says the UI does not know what your format is when it receives a number. If you send US dollars as a number and the website is in German, then would it need to have a rate converter or would is show the same amount in Euros or Dollars.

And since this could depend on where, which service and what rational, we are pretty much stuck with using pipes and formatting directives (especially in inputs) everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I know that an answer is accepted, but maybe it would be useful for you.

You can send locale to front end from the back end and then just apply a currency pipe.

C#:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]FooDto fooDto)        
{
    return Ok({Locale = "CAD"});
}
```

TypeScript:

```
myLocale: string;
```

HTML:

```
<p>A: {{ a | currency: myLocale }}</p>
```

More examples can be seen [here](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe).